# How to Compile Eclipse Project without 'res' directory

Tags: eclipse, build

I have one Android Eclipse project without 'res' directory in it.

It have only one file which is an common service, and i don't need the resource for this project.

So how can I tell eclipse that i don't need resources for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click your project -> `Properties`. Then `Java Build Path` -> `Source`, select the `res` entry and click `Remove`.

Comment: res directory is not in the Java Build Path -> Source.

Comment: @PP. You can also have a look at the file `.classpath` file in your workspace directory. Maybe you find a res entry there.

Answer (score 0):

You can just delete the folder assuming you are not using anything in the resources folder such as values, layouts, or images - this includes your application icons.

To delete the folder just right click it and delete it and make sure it is not in your Build Path.

You will not be able to get rid of the gen folder however, as Android build this dynamically since it is accessed through the SDK.

Comment: I don't have resource folder in my project it is already deleted, but Eclipse is giving error for missing res folder. it needs res folder for compiling project, but i don't want res folder as i don't have any resources.

Comment: yea, what does is say in the logcat?

Comment: res directory is missing, is the Error message.